# Main div does not enclose other divs

Tags: css, html

I have been looking for a solution for this for like a day or two but as I'm not used to coding web applications I can't seem to find the problem..

I have a hunch it has to do with that I do float two divs to the left.

**Question is why doesn't my main div enclose the whole page?**

This is my html..!

```
<body onLoad="initializePage()">
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#Button1').click(function() {

        });
    </script>
<input type="button" id="Button1" value="korv" onClick="hidedivs()" />
<div id="main">
    <div id="searchholder">
        <div id="slider" class="searching"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table id="mytable" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Sidor/Artiklar" class="nobg">Sidor/Artiklar</th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Mozrank">MozRank</th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="PR">PR</th>
                        <th scope="col" abbr="Dual 1.8GHz">Fri tillgång</th>
                        <th scope="col" colspan="2" abbr="Dual 2.5GHz">Välj själv</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr data_id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pr_domain")%>'>
                    <th scope="row" abbr="Model" class="spec"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "namn_domain")%> </th>
                    <td class="alt" ><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "moz_domain")%></td>
                    <td class="alt"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pr_domain")%></td>
                    <td class="alt"><b></b>
                        <input type='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "type_domain")%>' name='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idtag_domain")%>' value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "faccess_domain")%>' onClick="calculatePrice();disableTB(this.name);" />
                        "Fri tillgång" </td>
                    <td class="alt"><input type="radio" name='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idtag_domain")%>' value="0"  onclick="calculatePrice();enableTB(this.name, this.checked)" />
                        "Skriv ditt antal själv" </td>
                    <td class="alt" data_id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pr_domain")%>'><input type="text"  name='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "moz_domain")%>' id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idtag_domain")%>'  Enabled="false" Width="40px" onKeyUp="calculatePrice()" style="background-color:#eeeeee" /></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    <div id="pricingdetails" class="price">Priset för dina artiklar blir: </div>
</div>
```

And my .css styles are

```
.price
{
 font-family:"Verdana";
 font-size:40px;
 color:Green;
 float: left;
 border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
 border-top: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
 color: #797268;
 font: bold 10px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FFFFFF 0%, #EDEDED 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
 display: inline; 
 }

 div.searchholder
{
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -70px;
width: 480px;    
}

div.main
{
}

div.left
{
float: left;  
}
.searching
{
}
```

Comment: It would be really great to see this question at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). )

Comment: Cleaned up HTML formatting. :)

Comment: Is `HeaderTemplate`, `ItemTemplate` and `FooterTemplate` something ASP-specific? If not, your tags are not well-formed. e.g. your table opens within the HeaderTemplate, but doesn't close there. I'd suggest to move the HeaderTemplate immediately _after_ the table tag. Same applies to the FooterTemplate, which should close _before_ the end of the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that since the elements inside your `#main` `div` are floated, they're considered in a different flow than your `div`, and thus it doesn't resize to fit them. Ways to fix this are:

- Add `overflow: hidden;` to your `#main` styling.
- Float your `#main` by adding `float: left;`.
- Append this to your `#main` `div`: `<div style = "clear: both;"></div>` (this is the least preferable method).

Comment: There is no element with the class `main`.

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame I was looking at his CSS instead: `div.main`, oops. Although there's no need to downvote just because I used a class instead of an ID when referring to his `div`.

Comment: You should add a note that clearing elements are frowned upon.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the floats of the child elements for **#main**

Instead of doing what some of the others have suggested (adding an element for the purpose of clearing your floats; bad practice), use a pseudo-element. Just use the following CSS and voila!

```
#main::after {
 clear:both;
 content: "";
 display: table;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPGds/) This pink background is there to show the result of the above for **#main**.

Answer (score 1):

Your main div (`#main`) isn't floated yet you have floated elements inside it.

To clear the float add the CSS:

```
#main {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a clear before the ending  tag.

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: In what way is this a bad practice?

Comment: There is nothing incorrect about using clears with floats. How do you expect them to clear them self?

Comment: The markup should be completely ignorant of style and composition. That is the job of stylesheets (CSS). Mucking up the markup with clearing elements is a bad practice, plain and simple. The same effect can be accomplished with CSS, so there's really no need to add extra markup that adds nothing to the CONTENT of the page.

Comment: HTML is not content. HTML is the structure of the page.

Comment: @verheesj HTML is for semantics and that's it. Shmiddty is right, there shouldn't be empty elements. CSS should be used to undo what CSS started. Refer to my answer.

Comment: Sure, it is the structure (that describes the content therein), but it should have no bearing on the presentation of the content. Clearing elements aren't related to the structure of the page, they don't describe any content, and are used solely to correct a visual problem that is a result of unskilled developers and designers.